# How do I determine if ffmpeg can handle file?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have an application that splits video with `ffmpeg`.

In order to avoid errors, I would like to know if file selected by user is video or not.

Is there any `ffmpeg` command that would inform me whether `ffmpeg` can successfully handle the file selected or not (e.g. images and text files selected should be marked as incorrect)?

Comment: ffmpeg actually can handle image and plaintext files -- it turns them into videos :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following command:

```
ffmpeg -i <file name>
```

If you have a file that can be handled you get an output like this:

> **ffmpeg -i KEY.mov**  ffmpeg version 1.2.1 Copyright (c)
>   2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers   built on Jun 13 2013 12:22:32 with
>   llvm-gcc 4.2.1 (LLVM build 2336.11.00)   configuration: --disable-yasm
>   libavutil      52. 18.100 / 52. 18.100   libavcodec     54. 92.100 /
>   54. 92.100   libavformat    54. 63.104 / 54. 63.104   libavdevice    54.  3.103 / 54.  3.103   libavfilter     3. 42.103 /  3. 42.103   libswscale      2.  2.100 /  2.  2.100   libswresample   0. 17.102 / 
>   0. 17.102 Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #0.0 : stereo Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'Sysmex_Mockup_KEY.mov':   Metadata:
>       major_brand     : qt
>       minor_version   : 537199360
>       compatible_brands: qt
>       creation_time   : 2013-04-19 14:54:18   Duration: 00:08:28.50, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2151 kb/s
>       **Stream #0:0(eng): Audio: pcm_s16le (sowt / 0x74776F73), 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 1411 kb/s**
>       Metadata:
>         creation_time   : 2013-04-19 15:02:07
>         handler_name    : Apple Alias-Datensteuerung
>       **Stream #0:1(eng): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1024x768, 737 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 3k tbn, 6k tbc**
>       Metadata:
>         creation_time   : 2013-04-19 15:02:07
>         handler_name    : Apple Alias-Datensteuerung

Otherwise the output looks like:

> **ffmpeg -i A_left.jpg**  ffmpeg version 1.2.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers   built on Jun 13 2013 12:22:32
>   with llvm-gcc 4.2.1 (LLVM build 2336.11.00)   configuration:
>   --disable-yasm   libavutil      52. 18.100 / 52. 18.100   libavcodec     54. 92.100 / 54. 92.100   libavformat    54. 63.104 / 54. 63.104   libavdevice    54.  3.103 / 54.  3.103   libavfilter     3. 42.103 / 
>   3. 42.103   libswscale      2.  2.100 /  2.  2.100   libswresample   0. 17.102 /  0. 17.102
>   **Input #0, image2, from 'IWABD_1280_A_left.jpg':   Duration: 00:00:00.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A**
>       Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj444p, 1280x1024 [SAR 100:100 DAR 5:4], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc

Comment: The easiest way (although probably not completely bulletproof) would be to check for the existence of **" fps, "** (ignore the " and note space before and after) in the output. If it's there, ffmpeg can handle it.

Comment: @Richard certainly not bulletproof, since that will break on audio-only files (which may or may not be what the OP wants)